# Setting up GTK+ on Mac

Tags: gtk

I'm trying to set up GTK on Mac but keep getting errors while compiling my code. I'm new to Mac so don't have a lot of knowledge. I installed GTK using homebrew. The current version installed is GTK 2.24.28_2. While compiling the program I get the following errors:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config --cflags gtk+2.24.28_2'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pkg-config --libs gtk+2.24.28_2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong quote types. You want backticks, `` ` ``, which are to the left of the 1 key. You're using straight quotes, `'`, which are to the left of the Return key.

In addition, the name of the package that you give to `pkg-config` is just `gtk+-2.0`; the rest of the version number doesn't go there.

Technical explanation: the shell takes anything between `` `...` ``, runs it as a command, and inserts the output of that command back into the command line. The shell takes everything between `'...'` and places it as a single string unprocessed in the command line. So you're not running `pkg-config` at all; instead, you're passing the whole `pkg-config` invocation as an argument, which is not what you want. `pkg-config`'s job is to print the flags that gcc/clang need to find a package, so you use `` `...` `` to run `pkg-config` and copy those flags back into your gcc/clang command line instead.